# how to run config server when the port is args[0] in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, serversocket

This is my simple server program with java's `ServerSocket` class.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SimpleServerSocketTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while (true) 
        {
            try {
                if (args.length != 1) {
                    System.err.println("Usage: java StartServer <port>");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);

                System.out.println("Waiting for client...on " + port);
                Socket client = server.accept();

                System.out.println("Client from /" + client.getInetAddress() + " connected.");

                BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream());

                String nameClient = rdr.readLine();
                System.out.println("Client " + nameClient + " wants to start a game.");
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to run config the server 
but it keeps on saying this "Usage: java StartServer ".

I want to know how can I config the port when the port is `args[0]`.

This is in Eclipse, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

If it keeps saying "Usage: java StartServer" it therefore means this code

```
System.err.println("Usage: java StartServer <port>");
```

Is always been executed which means the condition

```
args.length != 1
```

Is always true. This could mean args.length = 0 or args.length > 1

Did you make eclipse pass the port number when running your application? That is did you configure any command line arguments to be used? I'm not a user eclipse so I can't help you here. See if this tutorial is helpful http://www.concretepage.com/ide/eclipse/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-java-program-in-eclipse or you could try to find some other tutorial.

Also make sure you didn't pass too many arguments than is required because that will also make the condition to return true. Just pass as many arguments to make the condition args.length != 1 fail which is having 1 argument.

You can also see this question with help configuring command line arguments in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

This is my practice for you.

1. Copy and complete your code.
2. Select menu clicking right button of your mouse, Run > Run Configurations

[image]

3. Select Arguments tab and type a port number whatever you want your server to wait for client connection then, run it.

[image]

4. Test it with your client socket program.

This is my practice using client socket programming.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
public class SimpleClientSocketTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader rdr = null;
        Socket sock = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;

        try{
            sock = new Socket("localhost", 9999);

            rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);

            String toServer = "hello...";
            out.println(toServer + "i wants to start a game.");

            String fromServer = rdr.readLine();
            System.out.println("server: " + fromServer);

            if(fromServer == null) System.exit(0);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try {
                rdr.close();
                out.flush();
                out.close();

                sock.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Send a message to the server first,

> out.println(toServer + "i wants to start a game.");

then, receive from the server.

> String fromServer = rdr.readLine();
>   System.out.println("server: " + fromServer);

There is one more thing to tell you about your server program.
This is a customized version of yours.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SimpleServerSocketTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java StartServer <port>");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        ServerSocket server = null;

        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (true) {
            BufferedReader rdr = null;
            PrintWriter out = null;
            int clientConnectionCnt = 0;

            try {

                System.out.println("1Waiting for client...on " + port);
                Socket client = server.accept();


                if(client.isConnected())
                {

                    System.out.println("Client from /" + client.getInetAddress() + " connected.");
                    String nameClient = null;

                    try {
                        rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                        out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);

                        System.out.println("clientConnectionCnt....." + clientConnectionCnt++);
                        nameClient = rdr.readLine();
                        out.println("Yes, You can");

                        if(nameClient == null) break;

                        System.out.println("Client: " + nameClient);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                        break;
                    } finally {
                        out.flush();
                        rdr.close();
                        out.close();
                        try {
                            client.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                break;
            } 
        }

        try {
            server.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

First, you should create a server socket outside of while statement not in a while.

```
try {
    server = new ServerSocket(port);
} catch (IOException e2) {
    e2.printStackTrace();
}
```

Just wait in a while statement util client socket accepting.

```
while (true) {
.... skip ...
    System.out.println("1Waiting for client...on " + port);
    Socket client = server.accept();
```

Then, create in/out stream of client socket.

```
rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
```

Finally, read and write a message with the socket's stream.

```
nameClient = rdr.readLine();
out.println("Yes, You can");
```

Regards, Rach.